# Delete simple Quotes from query expression SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, expression, etl

I´m working in SSIS and I create variable called CPP_Empresa like this:

```
"##CPP_"+@[User::cia]+"  "
```

Result is : `##CPP_ EMBE`
[image]

Problem is when I use this variable into another variable like this:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..'"+@[User::CPP_Empresa]+"' ' ) IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE'"+@[User::CPP_Empresa]+"'
```

If I evaluate this expression it returns

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..'##CPP_EMBE  ' ' ) IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE'##CPP_EMBE  '
```

As you can see I have an issue:

It added simple quotes into variable : `'##CPP_EMBE  '` I want to remove it.

How can I solve this issues? Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the single quotes from the expression:

```
"IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.."+@[User::CPP_Empresa]+" ' ) IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE "+@[User::CPP_Empresa]
```